# "Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined" when deploying Spring Boot WAR in Widlfy

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, log4j2, war

I'm trying to develop a web application in Spring Boot to run on WildFly Full 23.0.2.Final.
The WildFly server is already running some 3rd EAR and WAR modules.

Once I build my WAR file and place in deployments following message appears in Console log:

```
Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined
```

and starting this point no log events will appears from any entity, even from 3rd EAR and WAR modules.

I would like to use **Log4j2** or even simple `System.out.println`.

I'm pretty sure that my **pom.xml** is the reason, I have to make an exclusion for

```
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>  
                    <exclusion>                           
                         <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>  
                         <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>  
                    </exclusion>  
               </exclusions>
```

please help to understand and resolve the problem.

Full **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringTest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SpringTest</name>
    <description>SpringTest</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>  
                    <exclusion>                           
                         <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>  
                         <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>  
                    </exclusion>  
               </exclusions> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Session -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.22</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20180130</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <warName>${name}</warName>
                            <outputDirectory>C:\Test\wildfly\standalone\deployments</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You could try excluding logback with a wildcard. Something like `<artifactId>*</artifactId> `.

Comment: Why are you using an environment that is *specifically meant to eliminate the application server* (SpringBoot) inside of an application server?

Comment: Thank you @James R. Perkins, but it gave the same error `Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined`

Comment: @stdunbar , I have to exclude this part to avoid following conflict message  `ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 98) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."SpringTest-2.5.5.war".undertow-deployment: ` which leads to WAR deployment failure

Comment: @sGizmo, using wildfly with springboot, are you able to change log level at runtime? Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

@sGizmo Thanks your answer solved my issue. With Wildfly 26.1.1.Final, only adding `logging.level.root=info` to application.properties

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer, but I've found a better workaround that seems it should be added. You can set the `org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem` system property to `none` which will not attempt to reconfigure logging.

In WildFly this can be done via CLI or added to the `JAVA_OPTS`. The CLI command would look like:

```
/system-property=org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem:add(value=none)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a logging.properties file and put it on the classpath

**src/main/resources/logging.properties**

content of **logging.properties**:

handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=INFO

Comment: Thank you @Tambu , after  adding **logging.properties** , i got following error message while loading: `The configuration file in 'logging.properties' appears to be a J.U.L. configuration file. The log manager does not allow this type of configuration file` . So appears Wildfly is looking for the configuration in **application.properties** : `logging.level.root=info`  which seems to solve the problem.